# Gradle Task Sudden Termination

Tags: jenkins, hudson, gradle, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I will briefly explain the issue:

I am executing a gradle task through Hudson. The gradle task executes some groovy code.
If I cancel the Hudson job, executing the gradle task, then the gradle task ends abruptly, without completely executing the groovy code inside it.

Is there a way, where even though the gradle task terminates abruptly, a block of code will defiantly execute? This is to handle graceful exit. Like in java we have a finally block.

Any help with this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do it in Gradle since Hudson is controlling the JVM process which executes Gradle/Groovy code. But since you are using Hudson, you can try to use some plugins to achieve what you need. For example, you can create another job and use [Build Result Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin), which will start that job when your original job failed.